# How do I open an uexp file?

Tags: unreal-engine4, game-development, unreal-blueprint

I lost my unreal engine project and only have the packaged game. I managed to unpack the game with Game Extractor, but if the files are blueprints then there are 2 extracted files, one with the Function extension and one with uexp extension, if the files are meshes then there's a BodySetup file and an uexp file. The Function and the BodySetup have in their names uasset.Function respectively uasset.BodySetup. I tried changing the file type by deleting Function/BodySetup but when I copy the uasset file in an UE project it doesn't appear and I can't import either since Unreal has the problem that it doesn't recognize uasset files, so the only way to do this is by copying the file in the folder from the windows explorer, but as I said that doesn't work.

Do you know how can I get the actual uasset from the uexp or from the other 2 types of files?

I have no other way to recover my project and I'm kinda desperate and frustrated that I didn't save it on the cloud.

Answer (score 0):

When you build your project, it compiles/build the blueprint/assets - stripping away what is no longer needed. (ie all the stuff needed by the editor)

This means that you can't do what you want..

Some assets can be used after they are cooked through - but with limitations.
More about it can be found here:
https://docs.unrealengine.com/4.27/en-US/WorkingWithContent/CookedContent/